# error from dbus, no wifi after reboot

Tags: networking, wifi, dbus

### I corrupted the ssd, so until I get this error again (hopefully I won't, but I probably will because it already happened 2 times) I can't do anything.

I got a messagebox with this error when booting:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.blueman.Mechanism: permission denied
```

this is on a new and fresh system.
here is what I tried so far after some googling:

```bsh
sudo chmod 4754 /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
sudo chown root:messagebus /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

I connected to the internet with USB tethering from my phone and tried this:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dbus
```

I rebooted and wifi still doesn't work, though after the first 2 commands the ethernet port showed up and USB tethering works (but I don't know if they didn't work before, I'm assuming they didn't because the ethernet port didn't show up in the network panel applet).
also worth mentioning is that I had a sudo error before this happened (fixed by loging in to tty1 as root and running `chown root:root /etc/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`).

I have no idea what to do, but I really need wifi working again,
many thanks in advance!

Comment: I accidentally corrupted the ssd trying to back it up.
I'll update the question I get this error again.

Comment: You're fiddling with rights and ownership on important system files too carelessly. That usually only makes the situation worse.